# Getting the path/name of a the file with an included file?

Tags: php, include, constants, require

I've got a file `header.php` which is `require()'d` in just about every file within a particular package. One of it's uses is to check if the file `db_conn.php` exists, and if not redirect to a specific page - **except** when the file it's being `require()'d` into is `/admin/settings/index.php`.

However, I've only just realised, the constant `__FILE__` pertains to `header.php` and not the file it's `require()'d` into making it useless to use.

I'm wondering if it's at all possible to get the path and file name of the parent file within which `header.php` is `require()'d`?

**Just for reference, here's my code:**

```
if(file_exists($rp . "/_static/inc/db_conn.php")) {
    require $rp . "/_static/inc/db_conn.php";
} elseif(__FILE__ == $rp . "/admin/settings/index.php" && !file_exists($rp . "/_static/inc/db_conn.php")) {
    $init = true;
} else {
    header("Location:" . $server_name['plat'] . "/admin/settings/?error=1");
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, for the complex nested includes the only way I know is to use debug_backtrace()

however, for such a ordinary case, PHP_SELF of SCRIPT_FILENAME is suffice, I believe

Comment: Props, that's exactly what I needed! For anyone else, I used `realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])` which works perfectly in-line.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could fiddle around with debug_backtrace to find out. However, a better solution would be to set a variable in `/admin/settings/index.php` which indicates if it should look for `db_conn.php` or not. This is possible since the scope is inherited into the included file:

/admin/settings/index.php:

```
$check_for_dbfile = false;
```

db_conn.php:

```
if(!isset($check_for_dbfile)) {
   // do your check..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
$arr_scripts[] = __FILE__;
```

at the top of every file... and analyze later, if you need to.